# How to replace * in package.json file

Tags: node.js

I have a package.json file that lists all the dependencies I have with *'s, but I want the latest packages. I tried:

`npm install --save`

But that didn't replace the *'s in the file. I tried with empty strings as well, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of npm will update package.json when you run `npm update --save`, but [this appears to be broken in recent versions](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13555).

Alternatively, [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) can update your package.json.

Comment: Nope, this still leaves *'s in my package.json file.

Comment: What version of npm?  Works in 3.7.3 for me.

Comment: [Looks like this was broken in recent versions of npm.](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13555)

Answer (score 2):

npm understands some special keywords in its `package.json` one of them being `latest`

so you can edit your file manually with something like this :

```
'dependencies': {
  'jquery': 'latest'
}
```

this would always give you the latest available version of jquery no matter what.

Comment: But there's no way to tell npm, grab the latest, then edit my package.json file with '^whatever.was.downloaded'? Or something like that?

Comment: No you must edit the package file manually. It is important to note that `latest` is the last stable version while `*` is the last version, stable or alpha. But generally it's a bad practice because it means that npm can update some of your libraries to incompatible versions. It is better to lock it with some constraints such as `~2` to lock yourself into a major version.

Comment: hmm..... Okay, I'm making a little website starter for myself. The idea being to clone it, install, and start editing. It would make sense to use the latest stable version of each module at the start of a new project, but I wouldn't want to leave the word latest in there, because that would introduce breaking changes later.

Comment: Then you can simply do `npm install jquery --save` this will install yourself win the latest stable version for jquery and it is sufficient for most cases. In some cases you want a specific version or simply a specific major version without paying much attention to the minor version, in this case you need to update the file manually and you can use operators such as `~`, `>=`, `^` to specify constraints.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if it were one dependencies, but it's like 10 or 15.

Comment: For most of the cases a simple `npm install package --save` is enough. And if you want to install in other computers you just need the `package.json` and do a `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you replace everything with * and run `npm update --save`. 
This will write down the versions of the dependencies.

So

```
"dependencies": {
    "mongo": "*"
}
```

will become something like

```
"dependencies": {
    "mongo": "3.0.0"
}
```

EDIT: one user made a good point, * can get you in some incompatibility problems so you might want to downgrade or need to fix stuff after.